# Ошибка java.lang.IllegalStateException Android Studio

Tags: android

Пишу приложение на Android которое должно получать и выводить записи из mysql таблицы на сервере. Но оно выдает ошибку. SQL Запрос находится в отдельном файле на сервере к которому подключается программа и получает json строку.Для правильного вывода на экран написал adapter(class ListActivity)(его тестировал создав объект в приложени, работает праильно, проблема не в нем). Как я понял проблема в коде самого подключения к файлу на сервере. Подскажите в чем может быть причина?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListActivity boxAdapter;;
    String json_url;
    String JSON_STRING;
    String s;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            String json_url = "http://192.168.1.34/connect5.php";
            URL url = new URL(json_url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufread = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((inputStream),"cp1251"));
            StringBuilder stringBuild = new StringBuilder();
            while((JSON_STRING = bufread.readLine())!=null)
            {
                stringBuild.append(JSON_STRING+"\n");
            }
            bufread.close();
            inputStream.close();
            connection.disconnect();
            s = stringBuild.toString();

            Gson json = new Gson();

            java.lang.reflect.Type ClientAIType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<zaminu>>(){}.getType();
            ArrayList <zaminu> ClientAI = json.fromJson(s, ClientAIType);

            boxAdapter = new ListActivity(this, ClientAI);         
            ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listv);
            lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);                               
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }}
```

Comment: Стэктрейс ошибки покажите и отметьте строчку, в которой она выскакивает

Comment: Работать с сетью нужно в фоновом потоке